# Does research experience in mathematics help when applying to a master's degree in electrical engineering?

Tags: mathematics, masters, research-undergraduate, electrical-engineering

I am a second year electrical engineering undergraduate student. This summer, I found an opportunity to do research on geometry analysis with a mathematics professor. Can this help with both mathematics and electrical engineering master's applications?

I am interested in both mathematics and electrical engineering, and haven't decided which one to go for a master's degree.

Comment: What is the research topic? How applicable it is to electrical engineering could make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps you can add detail to be more specific than "math professor" as there is a wide variation between pure math, applied math, experimental math, mathematical physics and all these can be found in a math department.

Comment: It's a pure math project related to geometry analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a positive, but it is impossible to say how much since admissions committees have their own standards and are made up of individuals.

But, if you do well in the research and are able to get a good letter of recommendation from the PI then it will certainly indicate that you are serious about learning "stuff" and practicing the art. While (pure) math research is quite different from engineering research those who can focus and succeed are probably going to continue to succeed.

And certainly it is more positive, even for engineering, than not doing any research at all. And, it might help you decide which field you really want to pursue.

Applied math, on the other hand, might be much more applicable to engineering. And, of course, EE requires a lot of math in any case.